# PHP Multidimensional Array push and loop

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble understanding the coding in PHP, when it comes to multidimensional arrays and how to push.
The idea is to push a "Attribute" and a "Attribute value"

I have tried the formula below

```
   $i = 0;
   $array = array();
    foreach($node as $a)
    {
        $strAtt = $node->PROP[$i]->attributes();
        $strVal = $node->PROP[$i]->PVAL;

        $output = $output.$strAtt." : ".$strVal."<BR>";
        $array[] = ($strAtt => $strVal);
```

The **$array[] = ($strAtt => $strVal);** doesnt give me much success.
I have tried **array_push($array, $strAtt => $strVal)** - no luck..

As an extra questions, how do I loop trough the array and print me multidimensional values ?.

**NEW CODE**

```
while ($z->name === 'RECORD')
{

$node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());

$Print = FALSE;
$output = "";
$i = 0;
foreach($node as $a)
{
    $strAtt = $node->PROP[$i]->attributes();
    $strVal = $node->PROP[$i]->PVAL;

    $output = $output.$strAtt." : ".$strVal."<BR>";
    $array[$strAtt] = $strVal;

    if(($i == 6) && ($node->PROP[$i]->PVAL == $ProductLookup))
    {
        $Print = TRUE;
        $Product = $node->PROP[$i]->PVAL;
    }       

    $i++;
}
if($Print == TRUE) {
    echo $output;
    echo "Product : ".$Product."<br>";
    var_dump($array);
    }

    //print_r($array);
    $print = FALSE;

// go to next <product />
$z->next('RECORD');
}
```

New code added. For some reason my $array is totally empty when i dump it, although my $Output is full of text ?

Comment: `array_push( $array, array( $strAtt => $strVal ));`

Comment: You can go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12681587/1426743) to understand how array works in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting an "associative" array and not necessarily a multi-dimensional array. For associative arrays you don't use array_push. Just do this:

```
$array[$strAtt] = $strVal;
```

Then to loop the array just do this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key = $value\n";
}
```

Comment: I see you point, but will this add the next attribute and value to my array, or do i need something like $array = $array[$strAtt] = $strVal; ?

Comment: Thats right, *within the loop* you can assign the key and key value with something like `$newArray[$key] = $value` - in this example it outputs the value on each loop.

Comment: Hmnn...I have added my "new" code. For some reason my array is empty, although lots of text in the $Output variable...Any ideas ?

Comment: @UlrikVadstrup, I see your new code. Where in your code do you initialize your $array variable? You should have a place outside the while loop where you initialize the array with $array = array();

Answer (score 0):

Go through [array in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) , you will  understand how array works in php.
Besides if you want to add an element to a multidimensional array you can achieve like this :

```
$node = array ("key1"=> array (a,b) , "key2"=> array (c,d));
$array = array();
foreach ($node as $key=>$value) {
    $array [$key] = $value;
}
```

This will be the resulting `$array` after the loop :

```
array (
"key1"=> array (
a,b
) , 
"key2"=> 
array (c,d)
)
```

Hope that helps , happy coding :)

Comment: I think davidethell is on the right path. Maybe what i'm looking for is a "associative" array. I haven't solved my problem adding yet - though

Comment: @UlrikVadstrup , btw, this is also an associative array :p